# FFMPEG Trying to make a 8K 30 FPS MP4 video out of several hundred 8K PNG images

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I have been trying to make an 8K MP4 video @ 30 FPS out of a few hundred 8K PNG images using FFMPEG since forever, but to no avail. The PNG images are serially numbered, starting from 000000 and going like 000001, 000002, 000003 etc. They are also in the same folder as the FFMPEG directory.

This is the command I am using:

ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i 000%3d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

I have tried various other permutations of the command but no joy. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
I renamed all my PNG files to the following format: pic000.PNG, pic001.PNG, pic002.PNG etc.

After doing that I ran this command:
`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i "pic%03d.png" -level:v 6.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p  output.mp4 -report`

Here is the error report:

```
ffmpeg started on 2023-03-23 at 20:58:19
Report written to "ffmpeg-20230323-205819.log"
Log level: 48
Command line:
ffmpeg -i "picC:\\Users\\User\\Videos\\FFMPEG\\tif-to-mp4.bat3d.png" -framerate 30 -level:v 6.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4 -report
ffmpeg version 2022-01-30-git-1530b3f566-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable  libavutil      57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100
  libavcodec     59. 20.100 / 59. 20.100
  libavformat    59. 17.101 / 59. 17.101
  libavdevice    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
  libavfilter     8. 26.101 /  8. 26.101
  libswscale      6.  5.100 /  6.  5.100
  libswresample   4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
  libpostproc    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
     Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'picC:\Users\User\Videos\FFMPEG\tif-to-mp4.bat3d.png'.
Reading option '-framerate' ... matched as AVOption 'framerate' with argument '30'.
Reading option '-level:v' ... matched as AVOption 'level:v' with argument '6.0'.
Reading option '-pix_fmt' ... matched as option 'pix_fmt' (set pixel format) with argument 'yuv420p'.
Reading option 'output.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url picC:\Users\User\Videos\FFMPEG\tif-to-mp4.bat3d.png.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: picC:\Users\User\Videos\FFMPEG\tif-to-mp4.bat3d.png.
[NULL @ 000001716758de40] Opening 'picC:\Users\User\Videos\FFMPEG\tif-to-mp4.bat3d.png' for reading
picC:\Users\User\Videos\FFMPEG\tif-to-mp4.bat3d.png: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:picC:\Users\User\Videos\FFMPEG\tif-to-mp4.bat3d.png?
```

Comment: What happens?..

Comment: @Gyan Nothing really. I execute the BAT file but nothing happens. No file is outputted and I don't get any errors.

Thanks for commenting btw!

Comment: Add -report to the ffmpeg cmd and rerun. Share report file.

Comment: @Gyan I have modified my question to include the error report.

Comment: This is the input url that ffmpeg sees: `-i "picC:\\Users\\User\\Videos\\FFMPEG\\tif-to-mp4.bat3d.png"`  . See the last two lines.

Comment: @Gyan Why is that happening? I modified the source PNG file names to the pic000.png sequence and used -i pic%03d.png as the input argument. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you executing a bat file or just the ffmpeg command?

Comment: I am executing a bat file. Don't worry about it though. I was able to figure it out. 

Added an extra % sign like so: pic%%03d.png, which made it work. This is on Windows 10.